# Why is the JS code for Facebook's like button using a weird URL?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url

Looking at the code generated by the [developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), I'm talking about this line:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

It's such a weird URL, isn't it? I mean, the "right" way would be

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Is there any benefit of omitting `http:`? Is it even a valid URL?

Answer (score 2):

It will default to http or https depending on how the main page is loaded and not give mismatch errors.

Comment: (Yes, there is a benefit to omitting `http:` )

Comment: You are missing the more important part of the question. Is it even a valid URL? It's not something I can see from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax).

Comment: I found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx which explains a similar case in the section "Preventing Mixed Content Warnings (for web developers)". Whether it's legal or not I can't comment on, but this does explain what works :)